# How to auto-reload code when started by `play start`?

Tags: reload, playframework-2.0

You know, in play2, we can use `play ~run` to auto-reload the changed code without restarting.

But now I have to use `play start` to start my play application on a public server, to let some users use and test.

Is there any way to let play still auto-reload?

Comment: What do you want to do - replace the code on the server?

Comment: Right. Replace files with new modified files.

Answer (score 2):

No, that's the difference between `run` and `start`

So you just need to stop the app and run it again with:

`play stop`

or

```
kill `cat RUNNING_PID`
```

if it's `dist` version without play console

Edit: For keep running the application you should start two instances of the application and use ie. [lighthttpd](/questions/tagged/lighthttpd) as a load balancer: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/HTTPServer (section **Set-up with lighttpd**)

Comment: nginx can also be used http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/HTTPServer

In my config I have defined an upstream with two servers and I pass http://datagol-backend/ to the proxy_pass directive.

upstream play-backend {
  server 127.0.0.1:9001;
  server 127.0.0.1:9002;
}

Comment: @philix yes, you can use your favorit HTTP server - nginx is very good load balancer as well.